# How to open a specific file based on filename in php?

Tags: php

**I need to open an HTML file which is inside nested folders.**

for example:

*USERDATA\FILES*
Inside FILES- 8111,8114,8333,8585 (these are the folder names inside FILES)

I should pick up the folder 8585

Inside this FILES folder, I have 1 to 4 folders, the folder names will be in number.  I should pick up the folder which has the maximum number.
How to do that?

note: since it is sorted, the file with the maximum number will be at last.

Comment: Read the contents of the file, explode via `,` and grab the last key of the array.

Comment: I see that you are a very new user. New users are very important to us and we'd like to help you be more successful on this site. Please take a look at this [Help Article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking a good question that's likely to get a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Use scandir function and sort desc folder name.

```
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => somedir
    [1] => foo.txt
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => ..
    [4] => .
)
```

[PHP::scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)